# The Publishing feature must be deactivated on all sites before the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature can be deactivated

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to deploy Content from one site collection to another site collection.
When I was creating Path from central admin I got a error. I google the error and found that I need to clear all the error from Content Deployment Source Status. When I was at this page. I got this page:
[image]

So I was Deactivating ProjectBasedPolicy feature. For that I went to Site Collection Feature and Deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure". But When I Confirm Deactivate I got following Error

> The Publishing feature must be deactivated on all sites before the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature can be deactivated.

I don't know which features I need to deactivate first now or where to go.

Comment: I guess, you went to the "site collection features" to deactivate it, instead try it in the "Site Features".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deactivate a Site Feature called "SharePoint Server Publishing" first before deactivating a Site Collection Feature "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure".

Go to Site Settings -> Manage site features (under Site Actions) and deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing". Then go to Site collection features (under Site Collection Administration) and deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure". The former site feature is dependant on the latter, therefor you can't leave that one active and the other one not.

Comment: If anyone is trying to find what sites have the active "SharePoint Server Publishing", you may go to content and structure, and find the sites with the Publishing site icons (like a tree sturcture)